# Flat file parser routine

Tags: c#

We have a flat file.The First five characters on each line determines which type the line belongs to.
Each type has few fields and all are fixed length. How do i go about parsing the file and store it in a database?

Couple of options:

1) Create a XML template for each type and based on the first five characters determine which template to use to parse the line

.

```
<FileMap>
    <Field Name="FirstName" Start="0" Length="5"/>
    <Field Name="LastName" Start="5" Length="10"/>
    <Field Name="Address" Start="15" Length="15"/>
    <Field Name="City" Start="30" Length="14"/>
    <Field Name="State" Start="44" Length="2"/>
    <Field Name="Zip" Start="46" Length="5"/>
</FileMap>
```

2) Use fileHelpers library (http://www.filehelpers.net/)

Any other suggestions? Please let me know

Answer (score 3):

The [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class does a very good job of parsing structured text files.  You can use it from C#. Just add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, and a `using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` statement in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple string IndexOf, Substring will not suffice?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways, possible not the best, but just as an example - is to use layouted structures for this:

```
...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Type1
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
   public char[] FirstName;

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
   public char[] LasteName;

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)] 
   public char[] Address;

   ...
}
```

And usage will be following:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"D:\flatfile.txt"))
{
  string line = reader.ReadLine();

  string code = line.Substring(0, 5);

  // Add your structures factory realization 
  Type type = Factory.GetStructureByCode(code);

  string typeInitializtion = line.Substring(5, (line.Length - 5));

  byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(typeInitializtion);

  //Allocate amount of memoty
  IntPtr safePrt = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(type));

  //Copy 'bytes' byte buffer into memmory allocated
  Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, safePrt, bytes.Length);

  //Map structure to pointer
  var myStructure = Marshal.PtrToStructure(safePrt, type);
}
```

You can find nice description about structure layout usage [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/).

Btw, you can use strings instead of char array as property type with following attribute:

```
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
  public string FirstName;
```

but in this case last character of the string will be lost - it is replaced with '/0' (treated as nul-terminated string).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to roll your own: associate each type with an Insert command, a capturing RegExp, and a mapping from RegExp group to command parameter.