# How to parse text file with dynamic delimiter

Tags: c#, parsing

Format of the text file (whitespaces replaced with dots for clarity):

```
1....2...23....a....5
3.........4...bc...35
```

Need to parse this file to jagged array like this:

```
{
    {"1", "2", "23", "a", "5"},
    {"3", "", "4", "bc", "35"}
}
```

Anybody have ideas how to do this?

Update:

Minimum number of whitespaces is 3.
Line items can have different widths

```
ae18...1,1234....5,567.....-2,5
ae140....1,12...0,5673.....-2,3
aw1.............0,3573...-1,545
```

Comment: Very incomplete specification. What are the field-widths, can the fields be completely filled (eg 0 spaces in between) , ....

Comment: @HenkHolterman, thank you, i've improved the description

Comment: There still is no info/rule that enables detecting the empty field. Do you have fixed field-widths or do you need code that finds them out?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, i need code, that finds width of each column.

Comment: This is an excellent question. Excel does this, so you should be able to do it too.

Comment: To confirm, the first field will be left-aligned an all others right-aligned?

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, each line has the same length

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your example, it seems as if your input text file used a [fixed width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database), or flat file, format. If that is so, a simple strategy for parsing the file into a multidimensional array as you want is to read each line of the file, for each line get the different fixed columns and then trim away leading whitespace.

```
# Read next line from file
String line = readNextLineFromYourFile();
# Store the parsed line in a list of strings
List<String> parsedLine = new List<String>();
# Extract fixed width parts of the line, trim away whitespace and store in parsed line
parsedLine.Add(line.Substring(0,1).Trim());
parsedLine.Add(line.Substring(1,5).Trim());
parsedLine.Add(line.Substring(1,5).Trim());
# Store parsed line in the result
result.Add(parsedLine);
```

Comment: This post also has an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278980/flat-file-parser-routine

Answer (score 1):

Use the FileHelpers engine for fixed delimited http://www.filehelpers.net/

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to identify alpha-numerical expressions.

Comment: Then you can take matching parts and build your array.